# Pandas dataframe apply function

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

```
df.head()
     Ship Date  Cost Amount
0   2010-08-01  4257.23300
1   2010-08-01  9846.94540
2   2010-08-01  35.77764
3   2010-08-01  420.82920
4   2010-08-01  129.49638
```

I had to club the data week wise for which I did :

```
df['week_num'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Ship Date']).week
x = df.groupby('week_num').sum()
```

it produces a dataframe which looks like this:

```
         Cost Amount
week_num    
30       3.273473e+06
31       9.715421e+07
32       9.914568e+07
33       9.843721e+07
34       1.065546e+08
35       1.087598e+08
36       8.050456e+07
```

now I wanted to add a column with week and year information to do this I did:

```
def my_conc(row):
    return str(row['week_num'])+str('2011')
```

and

```
x['year_week'] = x.apply(my_conc,axis= 1)
```

This gives me an error message:

```
KeyError: ('week_num', u'occurred at index 30')
```

Now my questions are
1) Why groupby function produced a dataframe which looks a little odd as it doesn't have week_num as column name ? 
2) Is there a better way of producing the dataframe with grouped data ?
3) How to use apply function on the above dataframe `temp` ?

Comment: How did you `df.groupby('week_num').sum()` ? when the `df` had no `week_num` column.

Comment: @JohnGalt , sorry I missed an intermediate step. I have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Use `as_index=False` in `groupby` to not create index.

```
In [50]: df_grp = df.groupby('week_num', as_index=False).sum()
```

Then `apply` lambda function.

```
In [51]: df_grp['year_week'] = df_grp.apply(lambda x: str(x['week_num']) + '2011',
                                            axis=1)

In [52]: df_grp
Out[52]:
   week_num       Cost year_week
0        30    3273473    302011
1        31   97154210    312011
2        32   99145680    322011
3        33   98437210    332011
4        34  106554600    342011
5        35  108759800    352011
6        36   80504560    362011
```

Or use `df_grp.apply(lambda x: '%d2011' % x['week_num'], axis=1)`

Comment: It works fine! just another additional question, does pandas recognize week-year combination as date type in anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, I have no idea. When I try and replicate it, I just get an error.

On the other questions, Use the .dt accessor for groupby() functions ...

```
# get your data into a DataFrame
data = """Ship Date  Cost Amount
0   2010-08-01  4257.23300
1   2010-08-01  9846.94540
2   2010-08-01  35.77764
3   2010-08-01  420.82920
4   2010-08-01  129.49638
"""
from StringIO import StringIO # import from io for Python 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, index_col=0, sep='  ', skipinitialspace=True)

# make the dtype for the column datetime64[ns]
df['Ship Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Ship Date'])

# then you can use the .dt accessor to group on 
x = df.groupby(df['Ship Date'].dt.dayofyear).sum()
y = df.groupby(df['Ship Date'].dt.weekofyear).sum()
```

There are a host more of these .dt accessors ... [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components)

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. It throws an error `'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: You need to change the data type: pd.to_datetime(df['Ship Date'])

Comment: I had already done that. `df['Ship Date']` is a series for which dt attribute is not present.

Comment: What data type is it - what does df.info() return?